# что с AudioStream

Tags: java, аудио

Пишу все точности, как на видео, но Eclipse выдаёт ошибку: не существует AudioStream.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNzgAIhWL8Y

Есть ли нормальная информация про работу со звуком на русском?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитать о воспроизведении звука можно здесь: [habrahabr](https://habrahabr.ru/post/191422/).
Но я Вам посоветую, всё же, ознакомиться с документацией от `Oracle`, и постараться разобраться самим: [AudioSystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html) и [AudioInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html).